# JQuery function using sessionStorage not working with .aspx file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, session-storage

I'm trying to set up sessionStorage so the fields are filled with the data the user put on it.
The idea is that from search.aspx, I fill up the text field and search, on the check.aspx have a button to go back and have the searched value already stored in the field.
The data is stored in sessionStorage, but when going back from the check.aspx, it's not stored on the field.

The first aspx called search.aspx has the field and a button

```
<input type="text" runat="server" class="input_medium" placeholder="Add text" id="txtField" maxlength="15" ClientIDMode="Static" Value=""/>
<button type="button" class="boton" id="btn_Buscar" onclick="javascript:fnBuscaDoctos();">Buscar</button>
```

On the second aspx called check.aspx I have another button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnVolver" class="btn btnVolver" runat="server" Text="Nueva Búsqueda" OnClick="btnVolver_Click" />
```

with the data filled, i have a js called docsearch.js that has a function that stores on sessionStorage the value of the field

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn_Buscar').click(function () {
        var fieldValue = document.getElementById("txtField").value;
        sessionStorage.setItem("TextField", fieldValue);
    })
})
```

And also it has a function to load the value on the field

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnVolver').click(function () {
        var txt = sessionStorage.getItem("TextField");
        document.getElementById("txtField").value = txt;
    })
})
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unfamiliar with this language, and trying to learn. I'm trying to use sessionStorage. what I meant is that the data is stored properly, but I can't retrieve it with the second function.

Comment: `var txt = sessiionStorage.getItem("TextField");`  You have a typo in your logic here.  Also you say you want to set it on one page, and use it on another page.  The only way this will work with `sessionStorage` is if you are in the same browser window/tab for both pages, as sessionStorage is not shared across tabs.  It only exists for the tab that it was set in, and is destroyed when that tab closes.

Comment: If you want it to be accessable in different tabs, you will have to use `localStorage` instead.

Comment: I typed manually the code here, the typo isn't in the code. I do mean to use the information in one tab for both pages.

Comment: Then I don't see any apparent reasons why this logic would not work.  You just have to click the button on the first page to store it, and the second button on the second page to make it show

Comment: Exactly, and it's not working. When I check on the session storage on chrome, all the data I want stored is there, but for some reason, when I try to load it back from the second page, the field comes up empty.

Comment: Then you need to debug your secondary click handler.  Add console logs to verify that the handler is executing, that `txt` is getting the value, and that the `txtField` is found

Comment: when you say "second page" - what do you mean, exactly? how are you navigating between page 1 where data is saved to session and page 2 where it is failing to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

`<asp:Button ID="btnVolver"` is server control so ensure that its generated id is `btnVolver` so that your jquery click handler is executed.

You can add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to btnVolver declaration like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnVolver" ClientIDMode="Static" class="btn btnVolver" runat="server" Text="Nueva Búsqueda" OnClick="btnVolver_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I used same code and it worked normally for me except that i added jquery cdn on both pages.Now the second thing you must do is to use the javascript function on page head section maybe your javascript isn't referenced well or somehow not working so writing javascript directly on page may help you.